# How do I adjust what percentage of the graph is being used?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart, linechart

I'm going to apologize if this has already been asked, but I'm struggling to think of how to google this question:

I'm currently using a LineChart to display data as it is received. I want to show at most 360 points on the graph. (6 minutes, of once-per-second data) Since I want to indicate to the user how far along the data is on the 6-minute progress, I would like the line curve to only take up an appropriate amount of the graph. (Ie, 3 minutes of measurements should only take 50% of the available graph space)

What's currently happening:

[image: Current Graph]

What I'm trying to get:

picture:

[image: Desired Graph]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you want to show full range for X axis.

```
XAxis x = mChart.getXAxis();
x.setAxisMinimum(min_value);
x.setAxisMaximum(max_value); // may be 360?
```

Comment: Yep, that was it. Thank you!